# How to dynamically change SVG data URI as background image in REACT?

Tags: reactjs, svg, background-image, data-uri

I have a container that has a background image pattern. This pattern is passed in as a data URI specifically because I needed to dynamically change the fill of pattern through a prop I pass in when the container renders. **I need to dynamically change the SVG pattern URI with other SVGS URI's located in an external file.
Essentially creating a generative function that takes in SVG path/dataURI as props to create new backgrounds for the container. Open to any new solution and leads for this to work.**
Currently I have external svg files that I want to interchange the current uri path with. But I wonder how to do this since I also want to change the svg fill path dynamically with a prop.

Open to inject these svgs codes in different ways however the conditions are to able to dynamically change the fill color as well as SVG URI value in the background of the div container.

Here is what I have:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import './App.css';

const Container = styled.div`
   height: 50vh;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: ${props => props.bg};
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='${props => props.color}' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5L4.25 4l2.5-2.5L5.25 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
   background-size: cover;
`;


function App() {
   const [color, setColorChosen] = useState("green");
   const [bgChosen, setbgChosen] = useState("yellow");
   
  return (
     <>
         <Container bg={bgChosen} color={color}>
            
         </Container>
      </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: What is the problem or not working here?

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to read https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming because the styled components framework does not work the same way as plain JSX. Not reading all the docs is a sure-fire way way to run into exactly this problem.

Comment: Currrently I'm unsure how to make the 'data uri' in background image of styled component accept variables or props of svg code?